# Add JOINS in the usual FROM clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to understand if we can have the usual table names as well as JOINs together in a FROM clause.

For example - the following ones are obviously possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1,
     TABLE2 T2,
     TABLE3 T3
WHERE T1.A = T2.B
AND T2.C = T3.D
```

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1
     JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.A = T2.B
     JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T2.C = T3.D
```

But can we use the two together?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T1,
     TABLE2 T2,
     TABLE3 T3
     JOIN TABLE4 ON T4.X = T3.Y
WHERE T1.A = T2.B
AND T2.C = T3.D
```

I tried the above option but I always get a message that *T3.Y* could not be Bound.

Comment: Don't. Use joins. Always joins. Joins are great.

Comment: Don't think of comma-separated table names as "usual". This syntax has been **obsolete** for _more than 25 years now_, and is definitely the "unusual" way to do it.

Comment: Don't mix, too easy to get lost - especially when outer joins are involved. Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Your error is because you haven't aliased table4 as T4. Other than that, technically it's legal syntax; in every other aspect, it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can :D

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp1;
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp2;
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp3;
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp4') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp4;


CREATE TABLE #tmp1
    (
        id int
        , otherValue varchar(20)
    )
;


CREATE TABLE #tmp2
    (
        id int
        , otherValue varchar(20)
    )
;


CREATE TABLE #tmp3
    (
        id int
        , otherValue varchar(20)
    )
;


CREATE TABLE #tmp4
    (
        id int
        , otherValue varchar(20)
    )
;

INSERT INTO #tmp1 (id, otherValue) VALUES
(1,'who'),
(2,'what'),
(3,'when'),
(4, 'where'),
(5, 'why')
;

INSERT INTO #tmp2 (id, otherValue) VALUES
(1,'who'),
(2,'what'),
(3,'when'),
(4, 'where'),
(5, 'why')
;

INSERT INTO #tmp3 (id, otherValue) VALUES
(1,'who'),
(2,'what'),
(3,'when'),
(4, 'where'),
(5, 'why')
;

INSERT INTO #tmp4 (id, otherValue) VALUES
(1,'who'),
(2,'what'),
(3,'when'),
(4, 'where'),
(5, 'why')
;

SELECT *
FROM #tmp1 T1,
     #tmp2 T2,
     #tmp3 T3
     JOIN #tmp4 t4 ON T4.id = T3.id
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
AND T2.id = T3.id
```

[image]

Now, while this is possible, you should understand what the old school syntax actually does - it creates a Cartesian product without the WHERE clause. And, the only time you'd ever need to do this is when you actually want one. If you truly do not need a cartesian product you should use JOIN syntax, mostly because it makes code more readable but also helps other people put together how youre tables relate to each other (having to sift these out of the WHERE clause is a huge pain in the ass).

Check this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tmp1 T1,
     #tmp2 T2
```

[image]

Comment: IMO, this does actually answer the question while also providing justification on why this should not be done.

Comment: It also explains one good use for old school joins - Cartesian Products!

Comment: It may be required to use the implicit join syntax on certain tools or frameworks which don't support explicit joins.  Other than this, implicit join syntax should generally be avoided.  [Gordon Linoff agrees with this sentiment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do make a point to say you should use the JOIN syntax, but the question was about *if* you can, which you can (but shouldnt).

Answer (score 2):

Your final query is attempting to mix the old school pre ANSI-92 implicit join syntax with the proper explicit join syntax.

Regardless, you should not even be using the implicit join syntax at all.  One reason for this advice is that with the implicit syntax, the `WHERE` clause contains both the join conditions *and* the filtering logic.  This can lead to confusion when reading or refactoring the query.  Always use explicit joins when possible, and generally avoid putting commas into the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Note: ANSI SQL allows mixing implicit and explicit joins. (However, nothing I'd promote...)

Comment: It is possible on SQL Server as evidenced by @DougCoats https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab567484bc7cbbf25b95ef649fb1578c

Comment: I also dont agree with "never ever use them." On multiple occasions Ive needed Cartesian products. I also think knowing whats actually occurring under the hood to be important, even if its not useful per say on the day to day level.

Comment: That being said, for actual join purposes one should DEF use JOIN syntax

Comment: @DougCoats If you want a cartesian product, you should use "Cross Join". There's never an excuse to use the old syntax.

Comment: Isnt basically syntax sugar at that point though?